# pinia use state instead of this in actions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

In Vue3 compisition API，I don't usually use `this`

But pinia example is:

```
increment() {
  this.counter++
},
```

Dont want use `this` in action.Has any suggest?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1240

Comment: thank you! anyone who uses `this` should be fired. Also JS would be a much better language without `this`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a function (similar to a component setup()) to define a Store. Then you can declear actions and getters without calling this. [Official Doc Link](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html#basic-example)

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', () => {
  const count = ref(0)
  function increment() {
    count.value++
  }

  return { count, increment }
})
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1240

Comment: The most hilarious is that `this.` disappeared, but `.value` appeared :).

Comment: There is an experimental feature [reactivity transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#refs-vs-reactive-variables) that will help us not to use `.value`